# Different result when reading a registry key using VBScript in Administrator command prompt and normal command prompt

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I am trying to check the key is exist or not for user profile SID. But I can able to see the registry path in regedit.exe.
When I executing the script with normal command prompt the output is "Not exists" but when I execute the same script with administrator command prompt, the output is "is exist"

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" &  strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "S-1-5-21-2247315139-2362802784-487914187-1010\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\OneDriveSetup.exe"
strValueName = "DisplayName"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_USERS,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
If IsNull(strValue) Then
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key does not exist."
Else
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key exists."
End If
```

Comment: Is it just this key specifically or can the non administrator see any others?  Could simply be the check requires admin privileges to return anything but a null?

Comment: @Dave current account is also an admin account. It returns null

Comment: Yes - but processes won't run with admin privileges unless you tell them to.  Running from an administrator command prompt tells the script to run with admin rights.